# Express JS unusual middleware error

Tags: node.js, express

I am making an app with express.js and express-router.

I used to have a middle ware for use with my routers in this form:

`app.use('/route1', middleware1, routerForRoute)`

And the middleware worked and showed

`{middleware: "middleware"}`

Now I am doing

`app.use('/route1', routerForRoute)` but it is still showing

`{middleware: "middleware"}` which it is not supposed to do. I am super confused as to what is happening. Any idea?

Comment: can we have more of source code ? your middleware for example

Comment: Did you restart your server after the changes?

Comment: We need to see more code.